# What is the difference between remote repository and local repository in git?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I currently use Sourcetree as a tool for version control. When I want to clone existed repository, there are two repositories which are local repository and remote repository. Just wondering which one is the best  option to clone the repository.

[image: Sourcetree]

Comment: Why is there any choice? Which already exists, a remote repository or a local repository? If it is local, why do you want to clone it? Why do you want to clone _any_ repository? You have not described your current situation or your goal. (By the way, I use Sourcetree with dozens of repositories and yet I have never used Sourcetree to clone anything.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SourceTree terms:

A **local repository** is one that already exists or is already stored on your machine. It can be a repository that you already cloned before or was cloned outside of SourceTree (ex. using `git` commands on the command line). **You don't clone local repositories**, you just need to add their folders to the SourceTree interface, as indicated in the UI to "*drag & drop repository folders*" into SourceTree, so that they will appear in the UI.

A **remote repository** is one that exists somewhere else, in Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, or in any other server that hosts Git repositories. This is the one you need to **clone** into your own machine, where it can now become a **local** copy of the **remote repository**.

Comment: You *can* clone a local repository, to get a second local repository. Most people don't *want* to do that though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well this depends on what you mean by clone.

If you mean clone as in `git clone REPO_URL` (and I am assuming that you do mean that), then usually we clone the remote repository, due to the fact that all of the contributors in a project push their code to that repository. Thus by cloning it, you are able to get all of the available code that everyone can see.

Apart from that, you can't really clone someone else's *local*, as in on their file system, repository, unless they give it to you on a flash stick or you get a hold of their repo physically.

Otherwise, if you mean to just clone a repository as in make an exact copy of it and upload it to another provider, then you just have to decide which repo you want to copy and move to another place. Keep in mind that many services (GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket), do allow you to import other repositories fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

With source tree, you can either keep track of whats on your computer (local) or keep track of some repository online where more than one person works on (remote).

LOCAL clone: You can take this option if you are working on something on your local machine and noone else has to work on it. This would help with version control on your own work. So if you break something, you can roll back

REMOTE clone: If there is some work where more than 1 person works on, you can upload that on github(or some other online platform). Even if it is only you working on it, you can still upload your work so you can access it from whereever you are.